# Why the path goes to 'show' view not 'index' view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

route.rb:

```
map.resource :car_users
```

car_users_controller.rb:

```
class CarUsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @car_users = CarUsers.all
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

I created a link in a view:

```
link_to "SOMELINK", car_users_path
```

I thought the `car_users_path` will invoke the `index` method of the **controller** and render the `index.html.erb`, but it goes to the `show.html.erb` and invoke the `show` method in the controller. Why not `index`?

(I am working with **Rails v2.3.2**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just missing an `s`

```
map.resource :car_users
```

should be

```
map.resources :car_users
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
map.car_users '/car_users' :controller =>'car_users'
```